# Multiple JavaScript files accessing same Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a scenario where I have different views and I want them to have their respective JS files but all sharing the same controller. Is it possible in angular?

Comment: Yes. It surely is. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Did you try it? Would have been a simple way to answer your own question

Comment: We are having separate java-script file for each view. Along with the multiple views we also want to share the same controller between respective java-script file.Is it possible in angular?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the same controller using the `ng-controller` directive in your view, or specify the controller in your `$routeProvider`.

Do note that a new scope is created for each instance of the controller so they won't share the same data

Comment: should say *each instance of controller*

Comment: @NexusDuck - We are having separate java-script file for each view. Along with the multiple views we also want to share the same controller between respective java-script file.Is it possible in angular?

Comment: @charlietfl Correct, I will update my post

Comment: @user4850903 What do you mean by javascript file for each view? Views are generally described using HTML not javascript, I'm gonna have to see some code before I can answer that question